# Data being sent as query string instead of Form data

Tags: asp.net-mvc, form-data

In my form I see that the data is being sent as Querystring instead of form data (that I expect it to).

My page:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("AAForm", "Test", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "myAForm" }))
{
   <label for="a">A</label>
   <input id="aid" name="aname" style="width: 300px" required validationMessage="Select"/>
   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="aa" > Go </button>
   }
```

ControllerSignature

> public ActionResult GetValues(FormCollection formCollection){
>   //Some code }

And I am making an AJAX call to GetValues().

What could I be doing wrong? Pls let me know if I should be posting more information.

Another question: What is "_:" in the query string? And it has some random number value.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add an `[HttpPost]` attribute on your `ActionResult`.

Comment: Ok, I added the attribute and modified the ajax type to "POST" and it worked. Thanks for the tip. However, I would like to add that the same code without any modification worked in FireFox (13.0.1) and not on Chrome (Version 22.0.1229.94 m). Strange!

Comment: And any idea what the "_:" parameter I could be seeing in the query string (it's only present in Chrome)?

Comment: @rjv_rnjn it might be a timestamp, if you didn't set cache to false in your Ajax query... see http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/223710/JQuery-Ajax-Cache-Problems-on-IE , even if it's on IE, not chrome !

Comment: Sorry for the late response. I had the global ajax caching set to false (to take care of the IE problem I was facing). URL with querystring
http://localhost:54069/AllWebsites/GetValues?aID=4&filter%5Blogic%5D=and&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bfield%5D=aID&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Boperator%5D=eq&filter%5Bfilters%5D%5B0%5D%5Bvalue%5D=4& **_=1352131959972**

My question was about the last parameter I've highlighted.I'm using kendo drop down and the filter values are being sent by the kendo. {I can't figure out how to stop auto URL shortening}